# SFDC European Data Center experiences

Tags: security, performance, trust

I see a new EU5 instance on trust.salesforce.com which has a 'LON' hovertext over it, assumingly referring to London. I can imagine some companies might be interested in having their data hosted in the EU instead of US. Therefore:

1. is EU5 located on the new EU datacenter?
2. has anybody been moved there yet (or is it only for new customers)
3. do you notice any difference in e.g. response time or bandwidth?

****UPDATE****
Early april '15 we received the following update from SFDC:

> the decision was made to split your EU1 instance.
>
> During this maintenance, we will be splitting the EU1 instance into
>   two new instances, EU1 and EU4, and moving both instances to the new
>   UK data center.
>
> The window is currently targeted for the first weekend in August 2015.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A traceroute to `eu5.salesforce.com` shows `salesforce.edge3.london1.level3.net` as the last named hop. So it might indeed be located in London.

I currently have a DevOrg running there, which is pretty snappy for all kinds of processing. But this is mostly not an indicator for the performance of a Prod instance.

Comment: thanks Alexander. Accepting your answer since it answers most of my questions. If you (or anybody) has prod instance experiences, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 5):

This is where the Salesforce datacentres are listed :
https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000036j5BAAQ

This is part of the following Knowledge Base article #000181586 :
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-Services-Trust-and-Compliance-Documentation

Notice that EU5 is in the UK, as well as two sandbox pods :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your answer with the help article, from where the PDF is linked?

Comment: I did this just now